# How to add dependency to NPM package so that I get the latest version that ends with a specific tag

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, nw.js, semantic-versioning

The npm package for NW.js (package name "nw") has versions like this:

```
0.16.0-beta2sdk, 0.16.0-beta1sdk, 0.15.4, 0.15.4-sdk, 0.15.3, 0.15.3-sdk, 0.15.2, 0.15.2-sdk,...
```

I am currently using nw as a dependency in my package.json manifest, and I was wondering what version I need to specify to get "the latest version that ends with -sdk".

I have tried things like '*-sdk' and '0.x-sdk' but that didn't quite work as intended. I had a look at the syntax for semantic versioning but couldn't immediately find something for tags like this.

Anyone know if this can be done via semantic versioning syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add "latest" as the value in the packages.json file with the key being any package that you want to install like:

```
{
   "package_name": "latest"
}
```

Comment: But I don't just want the latest, I want the latest version with SDK functionality. As soon as 0.16.0 would be released as stable "latest" is probably going to install 0.16.0 and not 0.16.0-sdk.